# simple css issue - how to change anchor inside li if li:hover

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<ul class="horizmenu">
   <li>
      <a>Link</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pAgS9/  in jsfiddle

I want that If i hover the `li` area, the color of `a` text should change to white. Now if i hover, it is still black and only if i hover the `a`, then it becomes white.

how can i achieve this in css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
li:hover a {
    color: #F0F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.horizmenu {
    width:700px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.horizmenu li {
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
.horizmenu li:active,li:hover{
    background-color: #156ac6;  
    color:white;
}
.horizmenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.horizmenu li a:hover,a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GY2ge/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css class:

```
.horizmenu > li:hover > a
{
    color: white;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAgS9/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
.horizmenu li a:hover, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

into this:

```
.horizmenu li:hover, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.horizmenu li:hover, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
```